Can we store functions in a list with pre-set parameters just waiting for input?
I'm trying code up a class for data processing. It includes several functions like
class A:
    def func_1(self, input, param_1, param_2):
        some logics
        return res

    def func_2(self, input, param_3, param_4, param_5):
        some logics
        return res

    def func_3(self, input, param_6, param_7):
        some logics
        return res
    
    def pipeline(self, config, input ...):
        ????????

I wanted to build a pipeline that takes parameters from config file and just waiting for input to come, like this:
pipe = A.pipeline(config)

And the results would be something like this, with all the params pre-filled but the input yet to be given.
pipe = [self.func_1(input, param_1 = config.param_1, param_2 = config.param_2), self.func_2(input, param_3 = config.param_3, param_4 = config.param_4, param_5 = config.param_5), self.func_3(input, param_6 = config.param_6, param_7 = config.param_7)]

Then run the pipeline like this, applying input to those partially constructed functions and get results
for i in inputs:
    i = pipe[0](input = i)
    i = pipe[1](input = i)
    i = pipe[2](input = i)
    print(i)

This kind of look like pre-compiling. Is there a way to do this? or do I have to reconstruct the function for each input? anything is appreciated!

maybe use yield in pipeline for -->   yield func_1(par1,par2), func_2(par3,par4) ...
disclaimer : I'm not sure if I get the question right

You seem to have written the code already: pipe = [self.func_1(input, param_1 = ...]. This code can just drop into your def pipeline(self, ...): method.

This question is similar to: How can I bind arguments to a function in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is a case where it helps to know the technical term (binding arguments)

You can use functools.partial for something like this (quick and dirty):
import functools


class A:
    def func_1(self, input, param_1, param_2):
        # some logics
        return input * param_1 * param_2

    def func_2(self, input, param_3, param_4, param_5):
        return input * param_3 * param_4 * param_5

    def func_3(self, input, param_6, param_7):
        return input * param_6 * param_7

    def pipeline(self, config):
        return [
            functools.partial(self.func_1, param_1=config["param_1"], param_2=config["param_2"]),
            functools.partial(self.func_2, param_3=config["param_3"], param_4=config["param_4"], param_5=config["param_5"]),
        ]

pipeline = A().pipeline({"param_1": 1, "param_2": 2, "param_3": 3, "param_4": 4, "param_5": 5, "param_6": 5, "param_7": 7})

input_value = 1
for callable_function in pipeline:
    print(callable_function(input_value))


However, this seems a bit unpractical. You might want to update your question with what you actually want to achieve.
